# How to find storage location of application programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to find that whether an application is installed on external storage or internal storage ? This line only reutrns the path of the application :

```
String path = p.getApplicationInfo(info.packageName, 0).sourceDir;
```

Thanks in advance

For Example I want this :

Skype                  Internal Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did in this way :

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : packages)
{
   String storage = null;
   String appStorage = applicationStorage(appInfo);
   if(appStorage.startsWith("/data/"))
   {
      storage = "Internal";
   }
   else
   {
      storage = "SD Card";
   }
}
```

Comment: applicationStorage()??

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the list of applications(.apk) files installed on your device -

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

**Some of my device lists -**

```
package:/system/framework/framework-res.apk=android
package:/system/app/MusicPickerActivity.apk=com.MusicPickerActivity
package:/system/app/Kindle.apk=com.amazon.kindle
package:/system/app/BackupRestoreConfirmation.apk=com.android.backupconfirm
package:/system/app/Browser.apk=com.android.browser
package:/system/app/Calculator.apk=com.android.calculator2
package:/system/app/Calendar.apk=com.android.calendar
package:/system/app/CertInstaller.apk=com.android.certinstaller
package:/system/app/ChromeWithBrowser.apk=com.android.chrome
package:/system/app/Contacts.apk=com.android.contacts
package:/system/app/DefaultContainerService.apk=com.android.defcontainer
package:/system/app/DeskClock.apk=com.android.deskclock
package:/system/app/Email.apk=com.android.email
```

Lists installed packages that contain the term myapp-

> adb shell pm list packages |grep myapp

The cmd output:

> package:com.myapp.main

Show the install directory of the application `myapp` -

> adb shell pm path com.myapp.main

The cmd output:

> package:/data/app/com.myapp.main-2.apk

**NOTE:** If your application uses internal storage, then it will create a unique folder    that will only be accessible from your application. No other application can see what's in it. However, External storages are like public folders.

[Applications on SD card](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html) details..

Comment: I have the list of files. I just want to develop an applicaiton which will display the list of installed applications , and against each application , I want to display its storage location. For example :
Skype   Internal Storage

Answer (score 0):

List packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0); //PackageManager.GET_META_DATA

```
  for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {

     PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
     ApplicationInfo a = p.applicationInfo; 
     // skip system apps if they shall not be included
     if ((!includeSysApps) && ((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)) {
        continue;
     }
     App app = new App();
     app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
     app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
     app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
     app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
     CharSequence description = p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(packageManager);
     app.setDescription(description != null ? description.toString() : "");
     apps.add(app);

  }
```

Answer (score -3):

android:installLocation="internalOnly"

android:installLocation="preferExternal"

android:installLocation="auto"

Comment: you can install application on your choice as above

Comment: I want to find the storage of the applications , which are already installed